# understanding how to choose k objects from n objects with replacement

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have $n$ points. Pick $k$ of them with replacement. Assume the order does not matter. How can we do this?

Pick the first element, n ways to do this. since we dont replace same happens for second element and so forth. In total we must have $n^k$ ways. My notes say the correct answer is ${ n + k - 1 \choose k }$ which  I find mind blowing how this is possible.

Comment: [Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two_2)

Comment: In your first paragraph, you say that we are picking $k$ points with replacement.  In the second sentence of the second paragraph, you say we don't replace.  It looks like you meant to say, the point is replaced.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that the objects are distinguishable, each being of a certain unique type. Your answer would be correct if the order did matter but it does not. Therefore two ways to pick $k$ objects are distinguished only by the numbers of picked objects of each type.

There are altogether $n$ types, the total of chosen objects being $k$. Thus, the problem is reduced to the question in how many ways $k$ can be partitioned into $n$ non-negative parts. This is classical [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem with $k$ stars and $n-1$ bars, and the answer is indeed:
$$
\binom{k+n-1}{k}.
$$

Comment: This amounts to counting positive partitions of $n+k$ into $n$ parts, so imagine $n+k$ stars into which you place $n-1$ bars among the $n+k-1$ gaps, giving $n+k$ as an ordered sum of $n$ positive numbers.  Now subtract 1 from each summand and you have $k$ as an ordered sum of $n$ non-negative numbers.